# OpenLayers 6 ol.source.ImageWMS does not use/follow provided resolutions

Tags: openlayers

Even though layer source resolutions are as follows

```
var source = new ol.source.ImageWMS({
    url: this.url,
    params: parameters,
    ratio: 1,
    resolutions: [396.8757937515876, 132.2919312505292, 52.916772500211672, 26.458386250105836, 10.5833545000423344, 3.9687579375158754]
});
```

Images are being requested for intermediate resolutions, for example when resolution is `19.xxx` as reported by `map.getView().getResolution()`

FYI: map resolutions are different. Providing that range only `..., 66.1459656252646, 26.458386250105836, 13.229193125052918, ...`

Comment: The setting doesn't stop images being requested, it means whatever the view resolution images will be requested at the nearest resolution in the WMS options and stretched or compressed to fit the viewport.

Comment: In API documentation https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_ImageWMS-ImageWMS.html it says `Resolutions. If specified, requests will be made for these resolutions only`

Comment: Yes, requests to the source will be made for those resolutions.  If you watch network and check the request to the url you should find BBOX width divided by WIDTH will be for one of those resolutions.

Comment: You are right, could you post this as an answer